# Starting a CruiseControl Build from TFS

Tags: .net, build, tfs, cruisecontrol.net, tfsbuild

My team has migrated our source from another source control system to TFS. Our build leverages CruiseControl.NET. The first step of build migration is to continue our CC.NET build process but grab source from TFS. No problem.

The next step is starting to migrate towards a TFS-based build. The first step I am considering is launching a CC.NET build from within TFS. That way, TFS handles the triggers (e.g. a CI build based on check-ins) and build reporting, but CC.NET does the actual build.

**Has anyone done this kind of TFS/CC integration? Are there any gotcha's or caveats? What is the best way to launch the build and pick up the build results from CC.NET?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

why not keep your current CCNet setup?
just switch source control, and all is ok.
Because this is still your companies primary build server.

Next you can easily setup / experiment with the features of a pure tfs based build server.
I would not try to get the results from CCNet into tfs. Just for the reason that you will have to change X settings in your current build server setup, and this will disrupt the current build flow. CI / QA / production

let them run in parallel, just take another labeling system for tfs based for the moment.
this way you can make the switch when all things are ok, and it should not interfere with your current setup.